# how to parse the json from KUSTO query

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

In a table column, it has the json with below format:

```
{
"keySource": "Microsoft.Storage",
"services": {
"blob": {
"enabled": true,
"lastEnabledTime": "2022-09-27T05:54:20.5650000Z",
"keyType": "Account"
},
"file": {
"enabled": true,
"lastEnabledTime": "2022-09-27T05:54:20.5650000Z",
"keyType": "Account"
}
}
}
```

Question: how can I only get the enabled services name (such as "blob" and "file" in above example) in the output column?

Answer (score 0):

```
datatable(mycol:dynamic)
[
    dynamic
    (
        {
        "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage",
        "services": {
            "blob": {
            "enabled": true,
            "lastEnabledTime": "2022-09-27T05:54:20.5650000Z",
            "keyType": "Account"
            },
            "file": {
            "enabled": true,
            "lastEnabledTime": "2022-09-27T05:54:20.5650000Z",
            "keyType": "Account"
            }
        }
        }
    )
]
| mv-apply service =  mycol.services on 
 (
      extend service_name = tostring(bag_keys(service)[0])
    | summarize  make_list_if(service_name, service[service_name].enabled == true) 
 )    
| project-away mycol
```

| list_service_name |
| --- |
| ["blob","file"] |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA81RTWuEMBC951cETwoqIrWlgoceeuxpPVVEYpyVdKORJG5ru/3vjVndr9J7JxAmM+/NvMw0RJtTc3C7iQqeNlNPOkY9VCBsbHla37X3bF8nz9nBtBGjpOCk2HlhVAoltjrcaCFJC45/RiqQe0ZBGeCZbzM1F/XvKPSzrMYktBzBv05yovTzEZCzzjaPozgOoscgfsijJE3u0jgKk/skMvbq3NCN6nwaLO2JUjH22rkCfN/gt4zDP1OI/vI8VKID7vYBGQY+4WXsOMPYbjhc94BFj9FpqfChoW9WdGW2PlO0UFqyvnVr0lZGknIXgFdEpWepB6zGriOSfYLpQHZQcaZ0xbbuZS1/rVxcRstwGSHOMjtDzyjy5qrmB4MUb0B1QN7JdJT+A7/biaesAgAA)